# Monty Hall Lets Make A Deal Java Simulation 10000 iterations

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement, logic, probability

Im to create a program that runs Monty Hall's lets make a deal 10000 times and outputs the following statistics:

- the number of wins versus losses
- the number of times the player switched and won versus staying and
  winning.
- display the percentage of wins versus losses when switching and staying.

the desired output for the switching and winning vs staying and winning should be around 2/3 when switching. Which im getting, but only half of it; 33% when switching and 16% when staying. I don't know why the other 50% isn't showing up.
Pretty sure it has something to do with my 2nd switch statement but can't figure it out (probably due to lack of sleep).

What am I doing wrong? thanks in advance.

```
                int iterations; 
                for (iterations = 0; iterations < 10000; iterations++)
                {
                    int prizeIs = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);  
                    int compChoice = (int) ((Math.random() * 3) + 1);
                    int zonkIs = 0;
                    if ( prizeIs == compChoice )
                    {
                            boolean chooseFirstZonk = Math.random() < 0.5; // 50% chance
                            switch ( prizeIs ) 
                            {
                                case 1: if ( chooseFirstZonk ) 
                                        {
                                            zonkIs = 2;
                                        }    
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            zonkIs = 3;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                case 2: if ( chooseFirstZonk ) 
                                        {
                                            zonkIs = 1;
                                        }    
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            zonkIs = 3;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                case 3: if ( chooseFirstZonk ) 
                                        {
                                            zonkIs = 1;
                                        } 
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            zonkIs = 2;
                                        }
                                        break;
                                }
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 1 && compChoice == 2)
                        {
                            zonkIs = 3; 
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 1 && compChoice == 3 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 2; 
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 2 && compChoice == 1 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 3;
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 2 && compChoice == 3 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 1;
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 3 && compChoice == 1 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 2;
                        }
                        else if (prizeIs == 3 && compChoice == 2 )
                        {
                            zonkIs = 1;
                        }

                         //generating a 1 or 2 to decide whether to switch doors or not
                        int switchDoor = (int) (1 +  (Math.random() * 2));

                        switch ( switchDoor ) 
                        {
                            //not switching doors 
                            case 1:  
                                    {
                                        //since we didnt switch 
                                        //if compchoice == prize 
                                        //then thats considered a win 
                                        //for not switching 
                                        if (compChoice == prizeIs)
                                        {
                                            noSwitch++;
                                            wins++;
                                            games++;
                                        }
                                        //if we didnt win 
                                        //the games will be incremented by 1
                                        //later to use to calculate the losses 
                                        else
                                        {
                                            games++;
                                        }
                                    }    
                                    break;
                            //switch door
                            case 2:
                                    {
                                        //since we did switch 
                                        //if compchoice == prize 
                                        //then thats considered a loss 
                                        //because were switching 
                                        //to the door that has a zonk 
                                        if (compChoice == prizeIs)
                                        {
                                            games++;
                                        }

                                        //if compchoice != prize 
                                        //then thats considered a win 
                                        //because were switching from the door 
                                        //with a zonk to the door with the prize 
                                        else if(compChoice != prizeIs)
                                        {

                                            switches++;
                                            wins++;
                                            games++;
                                        }

                                    }
                        }
                if (iterations == 10000)
                {

                    double percentage = 100.0 * (switches/games);
                    double noswitchpercentage = 100.0 *(noSwitch/games);
                    System.out.println( "Switch percentage : " + percentage);
                    System.out.println( "No Switch percentage : " + noswitchpercentage);
                    System.out.println( "wins : "+ wins);
                    System.out.println("losses : " + (games - wins));
                    break;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only incrementing switch/noswitch when the player wins. Move the switch/noswitch increment outside of the if, and preferably the games increment outside of that whole switch block so it's not so duplicated.

... or maybe I didn't quite get what those variables are for. because that will get you 50% of games for each.

If you actually want to know win% for each strategy, you'll need to store the number of times you use each strategy, and the number of wins with that strategy, which is one more thing than you are currently storing. Then calculation is wins_with_strategy / plays_with_strategy, rather than dividing by total games.

Comment: I think what you're referring to is the switch that is used to assign the zonk to the proper door.
I added some comments to clarify what my thinking for the second switch is.
thanks.

Comment: The switches were fine. The variables are just named interestingly. If you look carefully, you'll see that you are counting the number of wins with switching in the variable `switches`.  You then calculate `switches/games` which means "number of games that were won *while switching* divided by total number of games *regardless of switching*" - total games is probably approximately 2\*number of games that switch was chosen in, which explains your strange half-results.